# NVIDIA 3Dvision glasses not working in xubuntu 16.04.4 LTS w/ nvidia geforce GT710 graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 3d

I am trying to get 3D stereo (stereoscopic vision) to work on our xubuntu machine using an NVIDIA geforce graphics card, and NVIDIA 3D vision glasses.  I have (tried) to follow the many suggestions but cannot get 3D stereo to work on our xubuntu machine.  I read that it should work with the NVIDIA GEFORCE graphics cards above the 400 series, so we thought we would try.

Here is the output of glxgears:
603 frames in 5.0 seconds = 120.411 FPS
600 frames in 5.0 seconds = 119.988 FPS

> glxgears -stereo
>   Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered, Stereo visual

Our set up is as follows:
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Codename:   xenial
Xubuntu with XFCE desktop environment.

Acer monitor that is “Nvidia 3D vision ready”.
Nvidia GeForce GT 710 graphics card.
Nvidia 3D vision emitter and glasses.

If I issue the command inxi, it shows our computer setup:
CPU~Quad core Intel Core i7-4790 (-HT-MCP-) speed/max~3803/4000 MHz Kernel~4.4.0-119-generic x86_64 Up~1 day Mem~1363.1/3886.2MB HDD~1000.2GB(36.3% used) Procs~263 Client~Shell inxi~2.2.35

The monitor and emitter work on a Windows 7 machine no problem (the emitter shows a green light). On the xubunt machine, the emitter shows a red flashing light.

```
I installed the NVIDIA X-server settings GUI.  
I installed the latest NVIDIA driver from the NVIDIA website.  
If I look at Software &Updates>Additional Drivers I see that
```

“Using NVIDIA binary driver-version 390.48 from nvidia-390” is selected.

lspci | egrep '3D|VGA'
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 128b (rev a1)

I edited the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file to include

Option         "Stereo" "10"
Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection

I have also tried the "nouveau" driver, but no 3D stereo.

Is there another place that needs editing?? Am i using the xorg.conf file? Any suggestions?The programs we wish to use are PyMOL and COOT.

Thanks in advance!